# Why does Word's 'Numbering' feature fail to add a number before this one paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word

Hereafter, I abbreviate WNF as Word's 'Numbering' feature located at `Home > Paragraph`.

[image]

Within a Multilevel List (where WNF functions  for all  other paragraphs), I have one paragraph of text that NF should have numbered at the cursor (which I have substituted with a red line).

But no number appears after multiple clicking on WNF's icon, and then clicking all of the formats under 'Numbering Library', as pictured below. Why? What is wrong with this one paragraph?

Comment: I think you forgot to post a picture

Comment: @InterLinked Sorry. Done now.

Comment: (1) "Indented text 2" definitely has a paragraph mark after it? Not a hard line end? (2) What are the paragraph styles, and do any of them have associated numbering? (2 may not be relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps (in order of increasing integers):

1. Start by numbering 1.1.
2. Then press enter to make #2 appear (which is where "The" will appear).
3. Go back to #1 and hit enter.
4. Press backspace and hit the tab button twice.

I think 1-4 will achieve what you want.

**Edit:**
Create a number list. Type 'asdf' on each line or some short string and hit enter until you have a list that looks like this:

```
    1. asdf
    2. asdf
    3. asdf
    etc...
    8. asdf
```

Then, on the line before the space where you want an indented paragraph without a number, press enter, backspace twice, and then tab twice. Then type your paragraph.

Does this make more sense now?

Comment: Following 1-3 produced [this formatting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0hs.png). But then how does this help? If I proceed to 4, then pressing backspace would delete the 1.2?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I do wish or `want an indented paragraph without a number`? The problem is the absence of a number, not the existence of one?

Comment: You can just type the paragraph in one of those numbers then, and then press enter on the lines before and after it and then indent the paragraph to where you want. To change the number, then right click it and select numbering style or change numbering value. Does this help?